# What to do with these darn OSBs

Tags: roof, waterproofing, shingles, asphalt, osb

So we just started replacing an old roof as the forecast seemed promising. All of a sudden, it changed to full on rain every day...

We have managed to remove half of the old roof (2 out of 4 sides) and put OSB3 sheathing covered with underlayment before the rain hit (no shingles). I'm not sure if it's standard or I might be using a wrong term, so just in case let me clarify - we're in Europe and the underlayment membrane we got we were told was waterproof and supposedly allows vapors from underneath to pass through - they call it "breathing membrane" or "vapor permeable membrane" I guess are the closest translations.

Anyway, we put it on using a hammer tacker, and as you probably can figure, it's far from perfect. It is wrinkled here and there and water seems to accumulate. There are about a dozen wet spots on the roof floor. As it was raining today, looking at it from the ground I could see a bunch of water leaking from between the membrane and the OSB end (the membrane sticks out a bit, so it's easy to tell).

Nevertheless the majority of water is being blocked by the membrane, if I'd have to guess I'd say less than 10% of the total OSB surface is being exposed to water directly.

Here is a very vague and disproportionate drawing of what I tried to explain:

[image]

- black lines represent OSBs
- blue lines represent the membrane which is laid out in 3 rows which overlap at the ends
- green dots represent staples, which are all over the place
- red represents where water is supposedly entering and reaching the OSBs, then continues on to drain to the end of the roof on top of the OSB and below the membrane.

I am tempted to put shingles on as fast as possible to prevent any more water from going in but I'm worried if the water that has already entered will be able to evaporate, or are the OSBs going to rot?

There seems to be more than a week straight of just rain every day, so I don't see the OSBs drying off anytime soon, it'll only get worse.

What's my best bet?

Comment: You lapped the higher elevation piece of underlayment over top of the lower elevation piece of underlayment so that the arrangement sheds water, right? The attic is vented such that the OSB can dry to the interior of the house with moisture escaping through the vents, right? You typically want to avoid sandwiching anything water sensitive between two moisture barriers, but if you've got hard constraints, then a semi-permeable membrane like yours can work around the constraints. You just have the one moisture barrier layer in the assembly?

Comment: @popham yes, higher rows of underlayment go on top of the lower ones. The attic is currently vented, kind of naturally, as there are openings on the roof floor we still haven't fixed and a fully vertical attic window that is constantly open, but I've just read on the web that OSB3 is impregnated (in our case on both sides) and has a harder time drying off? Furthermore when water is continuously dripping on top of it.. I'm not sure I understand the last question. Our setup is pretty basic, truss(es?), OSB, underlayment, asphalt shingles (not yet put on).

Comment: Where I live, there's nothing unusual at all with OSB wall and roof sheathing being exposed to the often rainy weather, during building construction, for weeks and even months.

Comment: The OSB will dry out, no problem.  Your problem is really just keeping the leaks from damaging your ceiling and/or insulation.

Comment: @Huesmann but if I put shingles on top aren't they going to prevent the trapped water from evaporating? The OSB is impregnated on both sides and I read somewhere that it acts as a moisture barrier, so water will *supposedly* not be able to reach the bottom side and evaporate from there?

Comment: No, the OSB can dry out from the other side too.  Unless you've somehow waterproofed the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were in the US, I would say "install the roofing," but I'm unfamiliar with European standards for OSB. I see "water resistant binders" associated with OSB3, so that's probably the same stuff that we use for roof paneling in the US (listed as "Exposure 1" grade). I saw an APA conformance document indicating that US suppliers ship to Europe, and I perceive that as corroboration.

Your subroof assembly can dry to the interior, so an installed roof will be a net good. You might place a fan in the attic to accelerate drying (removing the moist air as the water evaporates from the underside of the OSB). With only one panel face for the water to diffuse out of, I expect that it will take about twice as long to dry (twice as long versus a simplified model of the alternative case with no sun and no moisture barrier to maintain high humidity beside the top surface).

The barrier is punctured all over the place, so obviously it's imperfect, but if the shingles handle 99.5% of rain and snow, then 80% effectiveness from the barrier still takes that 99.5% up to 99.9%. Your 90% sounds pretty good to me, but that's just the personal feelings of an idiot on the subject.

For OSB rot, the problem is from persistently high moisture content, not a one time deal during construction.

Comment: We're complete beginners, this is the first time we're ever doing something like this, so my percentage assumptions could be way off in any direction. What you said about exposure 1 grade seems to add up with what I've been reading about OSBs, but as far as I understand it could be impregnated on either one side or both. I already asked this in another comment but it's important for me so I'll ask again. As ours are impregnated on both sides, is water from the top side going to be able to penetrate through the entire OSB and evaporate from the bottom (attic) side?

Comment: @php, this "impregnated" sounds like wrong information that circulates a lot in the US. There are products with a single rough face so that builders have good traction walking at heights. People often believe that the smooth alternative side has a wax coating. This is false. Wax may be used (see https://www.hexion.com/en-us/applications/oriented-strand-board#Wax%20Emulsions, for instance), but through the whole thickness of the panels. This is one method used to inhibit the swelling of wet panels. Porous paths from the underside of the panels will allow water out that entered from above.

Comment: @php, EN 300 is your analogue to the US standard. There's a slightly modified version of EN 1087 that they use for moisture testing that involves 2 hours in boiling water plus an additional hour in 20°C water. They anticipate some water exposure. It's fine as long as your roof doesn't expose the stuff to years of saturation.